# how are function parameters initialized implicitly?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm attempting to understand how are `image` and `imageData` populated. They are not declared anywhere. How does the parent function know what values to pass to these two parameters?

```
var Jimp = require("jimp");
module.exports = function (context, myBlob) {
    Jimp.read(myBlob, function(err, image) {
        image.getBuffer(Jimp.MIME_TIFF, function(error, imageData) {
            context.bindings.outputBlob = imageData;
            context.done();
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Because `getBuffer` expects a callback with a specific signature, which it calls with whatever it decides to call it with.

Comment: `image.getBuffer` always passes the same arguments. Changing the signature for the callback function won’t change that.

Comment: The same way this works: `function run(input, runthis) { runthis(input); } run("test", console.log);`. Jimp.read() etc. have been _designed_ such that rather than returning values, they "send values on by calling a function you given for that purpose". This is called the "callback" pattern, and you should be able to find quite a few decent tutorials that explain how it works - a lot of Node libraries heavily rely on you understanding it, so I can highly recommend reading up on it.

Comment: In the [`jimp` documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp#basic-usage) they work mainly with promises. I would suggest you do the same. Using callbacks is fine, but you have to be careful not to strand in [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Its not parent function who populate these .

image is populated by `Jimp.read` & imageData is populated by `image.getBuffer`.

The functions passed to `Jimp.read` & `image.getBuffer` are called callback functions

Comment: how could `Jimp.read` populate `image` if `Jimp.read` actually depends on `image`

Comment: also your answer contradicts what @Paflow said above, where `Jimp.read` populates `imageData`

Comment: `Jimp.read` does not depends on `image`. It gets called with an anonymous function, having a parameter `image`. Inside that function (I called it image_function in my explanation attempt above) that paremater can be used as usual and gets populated by Jimp.read at the moment of calling the anonymous function.

Answer (score 1):

You are providing a callback function in both cases (`read` and `getBuffer`) as the second parameter. When those functions finish their work, they call your callback functions, passing the data as the second parameter, and an error (or `null` if there's none) as the first parameter. Hence, the value is available and populated in the body of the callback functions.

Answer (score 1):

They are passed as parameters. Imagine `them` as something like

```
    function read(err, image_function) {
       let imageData = // do whatever to read some imageData from hard drive
       image_function(imageData);
    }

    function getBuffer(mimeType, callback_function) {
       // do whatever
       callback_function();
    }
```

Comment: this contradicts what @Oxi suggests below. could you please take a look?